# SQL Join on Like Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2017

I know this question has been asked a couple of times and i've tried to use the solution for my problem. Unfortunately it did not get me the output i wanted. I need to update ID column in one table by joining it to another table where the joining column does not have exact value.

```
TableA                                               TableB
EmpNo   EmpName      ID                              EmpNo          EmpName        ID    TermDate
101     John Doe     Null                            250termed_101  John Doe       250   11-15-2018
102     Jane Doe     Null                            251termed_102  Jane Doe       251   02-25-2019
101     Bryan Adams  Null                            252termed_101   Bryan Adams   252   03-12-2020
```

Here's what i tried but was unable to get the required output because the below query is giving me duplicates:

```
select *
from TableA as A left join
     TableB as B
     on B.EmpNo like '%' + A.EmpNo + '%' and A.EmpNo is not null
```

Output Required:

```
EmpNo   EmpName      ID
101     John Doe     250
102     Jane Doe     251
101     Bryan Adams  252
```

I need to populate ID column from TableB into TableA by joining these 2 tables on EmpNo. For the first record, John Doe is terminated on 11-15-2018 and his employee number is assigned to Bryan Adams with unique ID. I need to populate the ID column from TableB into Table A for the corresponding employee who had that number at the time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be a little more vague than "failed"? Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @HABO, was that sarcastic, or did you mean "a little more specific"?

Comment: What do you join the 2 tables on?  If you don't put join condition, it will do cartesian product of the 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

You seem on the right path, the update statement should look like the following, also notice how I am making the like comparison more accurate:

```
update A SET
    ID = B.ID
from 
    TableA as A 
    left join TableB as B on 
        B.EmpNo like '%_' + A.EmpNo and 
        A.EmpNo is not null;
```

that will break when you have 101 and 1101 or 2101, so it's not a good match, so let's revisit:

```
update A SET
        ID = B.ID
    from 
        TableA as A 
        inner join TableB as B on 
            RIGHT(B.EmpNo, len(B.EmpNo) - charindex('_', B.EmpNo)) = A.EmpNo
            A.EmpNo is not null and --you don't need this, 
            charindex('_', B.EmpNo) > 0;--needed, otherwise you get string errors
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is truly that you're getting duplicates that you don't want, you can throw a `DISTINCT` in. But your problem is in the data: Bryan Adams and John Doe both have employee numbers of 101, so they look duplicated when you join to TableB.

This SQL Fiddle might help you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f30476/10